# CSS para alert() o confirm() de JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5

me gustaría que me ayudaran a darle css a los `alert()` y a los `confirm()` de **javascript**, para que mis mensajes sean algo elegantes, no quiero optar por un modal solo para confirmaciones, así que si alguien supiera como lo realizo se lo agradecería.

```js
$("#confirm").click(function(){
  var bool=confirm("Seguro de eliminar el dato?");
  if(bool){
    alert("se elimino correctamente");
  }else{
    alert("cancelo la solicitud");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="confirm">confirmar eliminacion</button>
```

Comment: Aquí tienes la respuesta a tu pregunta https://desarrollo-geek.net/tutoriales/javascript/javascript-alert-confirm-prompt/

Comment: Se te agradece la intención de ayuda, pero deberías leer [answer], pues los aportes que son solo enlaces se consideran de baja calidad

Comment: Ademas el enlace solo muestra alert-confirm tal cual muestra el navegador.

Comment: Disculpad que me meta dónde no me llaman, pero Aprendiz está equivocado, pues Deker no ha respondido sino comentado y es el lugar apropiado.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Lamentablemente **no es posible**.

Los `alert`, `prompt` y `confirm` son creados por el navegador y sus estilos visuales dependen enteramente de éste.

Ejemplo de Navegadores:

### Chrome

[image: Chrome]

### Edge

[image: Edge]

### Firefox

[image: Firefox]

### Internet Explorer

[image: Internet Explorer]

No forman parte del DOM y por lo tanto no se les puede aplicar estilos ni por CSS ni por JavaScript.

Lo único que puedes hacer es precisamente lo que mencionas que no querías: **Utilizar un modal de alguna librería de tu preferencia o hacer el código tú mismo**.

Comment: En realidad quiero evitar los modals, bueno gracias por la respuesta, mejor los dejo asi ya nomas

Answer (score 9):

No es posible aplicar reglas de css para editar los `alert()` o `confirm()`.

Te recomiendo [Bootbox.js](http://bootboxjs.com/), aunque sean modals, son muy fáciles de usar y también tienen la función del confirm.

```
bootbox.confirm({
    title: "Eliminar Datos",
    message: "Seguro de eliminar el dato?.",
    buttons: {
        cancel: {
            label: '<i class="fa fa-times"></i> Cancelar'
        },
        confirm: {
            label: '<i class="fa fa-check"></i> Confirmar'
        }
    },
    callback: function (result) {
        bootbox.alert({
            message: 'Resultado: ' + result
        })
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Hay una librería muy buena, [AlertifyJS](http://alertifyjs.com/).

Es responsive y usa jQuery, o sea que tiene soporte en casi todos los navegadores viejos. Puedes hacer un confirm bonito y funcional solo con estas líneas de código.

```js
alertify.confirm("This is a confirm dialog.",
  function() {
    alertify.success('Ok');
  },
  function() {
    alertify.error('Cancel');
  }
);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.11.0/build/css/alertify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.11.0/build/alertify.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 6):

Te recomiendo utilizar sweet alert, checa el link: http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/

```
function delete(id){
   swal({
    title: Eliminar,
    text: Deseas Eliminar el registro?,
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#f7505a',
    cancelButtonColor: '#f7505a',
    confirmButtonText: 'OK',
    cancelButtonText: 'NO'

}).then(function() {
    swal'Registro Eliminado';
})
```

}

**Ampliando la respuesta, descarga la librería y llama a tu función. Nota: en el link vienen más ejemplos para su uso.**

Comment: Hola leo_vilchis, en lugar de solo dejar un enlace deberías colocar la respuesta aquí directamente. Dejar solo un link sin más explicación no es considerada una buena respuesta en este sitio. Lee la parte que dice **Ofrece contexto para los enlaces** de [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Agrega un ejemplo a tu pregunta para que sea una gran aporte, una respuesta de un solo link puede perderse cuando ya no este disponible el servicio

Answer (score 4):

Puedes usar SweetAlert es muy amigable

```js
$('#btnPromt').click(function(){
    swal({
        title: "Seguro que quieres hacer esto?",
          text: "Esta acción ya no se podrá deshacer, Así que piénsalo bien.",
          type: "warning",
          showCancelButton: true,
          confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
          cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
          confirmButtonText: 'Si, estoy seguro',
          cancelButtonText: "Cancelar"
        });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.8.0/sweetalert2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.8.0/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnPromt">Mostrar confirmacion</button>
```

Link : [Sitio web](https://sweetalert2.github.io/)

Answer (score 3):

Puedes utilizar modales para mandar alertas, un modal lo puedes diseñar a tu gusto y se verá igual en todos los navegadores.

> [W3S Modal](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp)

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var btnSi = document.getElementById("myBtnSi");
var btnNo = document.getElementById("myBtnNo");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// Get the button that opens the modal
var mensaje = document.getElementById("myMensaje");

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    mensaje.textContent  = "Seguro de eliminar el dato?";
    btnSi.style.display = "block";
    btnNo.style.display = "block";
}

btnSi.onclick = function() {
    mensaje.textContent  = "se elimino correctamente";
    btnSi.style.display = "none";
    btnNo.style.display = "none";
}

btnNo.onclick = function() {
    mensaje.textContent  = "cancelo la solicitud";
    btnSi.style.display = "none";
    btnNo.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Eliminar</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p id="myMensaje"></p>
    <button id="myBtnSi">Aceptar</button>
    <button id="myBtnNo">Cancelar</button>
  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Mira , si lo que buscas es reemplazar funcionalidad total sobre este método `( Alert() ; confirm () )`

Lo que podrías hacer es un override de la función, directamente lo que haces es sobrescribir dicho método.

```
function alert(message) { 
    console.info(message);
}
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

lamentablemente no se puede desde el navegador solamente lo puedes simular uno framework que uso yo usualmente  para eso es  : **Alertify JS**

aqui esta su documentacion en ingles:
[alertifyjs](https://alertifyjs.com)

y aqui tienes un ejemplo sencillo:

```js
if(!alertify.myAlert){
  //define a new dialog
  alertify.dialog('myAlert',function(){
    return{
      main:function(message){
        this.message = message;
      },
      setup:function(){
          return { 
            buttons:[{text: "cool!", key:27/*Esc*/}],
            focus: { element:0 }
          };
      },
      prepare:function(){
        this.setContent(this.message);
      }
  }});
}
//launch it.
alertify.myAlert("Browser dialogs made easy!");
```

si quieres ver ejemplo mira aqui: 
[ejemplos](https://alertifyjs.com/examples.html)

Comment: Esa librería alguien ya la recomendó. https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/119578/92764

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que utilices el framework de boostrap para que le des tus estilos te dejo un ejemplo:

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Saludos.

Comment: muchas gracias por la sugerencia, conosco muy bien bootstrap y sus modales, pero en realidad me gustaria darle estilo solo a los `confirm` de `javascript`

Answer (score 0):

Si se puede, pero debes pisar las funciones alert() y confirm(), un ejemplo que hice para jQuery.

Siendo "msg" el mensaje que necesitas y "type" una simple clase que puedes usar para pintar la alerta.

```js
function alert(msg, type){
    var html =  '<div class="alertContainer '+type+'">\n';
    html +=     '   <div class="mensajeAlert">'+msg+'</div>\n';
    html +=     '   <div class="cerrarAlert">x</div>\n';
    html +=     '</div>';
    jQuery('body').append(html);
    window.setTimeout(function(){jQuery('.alertContainer').addClass('active')}, 500);
    jQuery('.cerrarAlert').click(function(){
        jQuery('.alertContainer').removeClass('active');
        window.setTimeout(function(){jQuery('.alertContainer').remove()}, 500);
    });
}

alert('Este es un mensaje de error', 'error');
```

```css
.alertContainer{
    width:400px;
    height:100px;
    border:10px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:14px;
    position:fixed;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-200px;
    margin-top:-50px;
    padding:30px;
    z-index: 10000;
    border-radius:3px;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50px);
    transition:all ease .3s;
}
.alertContainer.error{
    background:rgb(202, 80, 80);;
}
.alertContainer.warning{
    background:#FB9E57;
}
.alertContainer.info{
    background:#847DA2;
}
.alertContainer .cerrarAlert{
    position: absolute;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    border-radius:100px;
    background:#3a3a3a;
    border:2px solid #fff;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 12px;
    top:-10px;
    right:-10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px -2px #333;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family:'Lato', sans-serif;
}
.alertContainer.active{
    transform: translateY(0px);
    opacity: 1;
}
.alertContainer .mensajeAlert{
    font-size:16px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family:'Lato', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
```

En el caso de los Confirm es lo mismo, pero agregale un boton, los confirm son de tipo boolean (True o False).

Comment: ese alert que agregastes en realidad es algo que emulastes , es un div con un z-index mayor a la pagina