# cómo hacer alerta en php con imágenes

Tags: php, javascript

Necesito hacer una alerta que me arroje como resultado una imagen.

O mejor dicho, que al ingresar al index de la página, inmediatamente me aparezca un recuadro (como una alerta) con una imagen y que la persona pueda darle **Aceptar** o **X** y lo saque de ese recuadro y lo deje en el index para ingresar a la sesión.

El código que tengo es el siguiente, no sé si esté bien.

```
<script>alert("img/imagen.jpg")</script>
```

Comment: En JS los dialogos de `alert` [estan definidos y no se pueden modificar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/94842/css-para-alert-o-confirm-de-javascript) pero puedes crear tu uno modal propio. Investiga como hacerlo y si en el proceso tienes problemas concretos o errores pregunta aqui. Una de las respuestas de la pregunta enlazada contiene un ejemplo. Un saludo

Comment: No puede mostrar una imagen dentro del cuadro de alerta nativa de JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal y como [@lois6b](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/15855/lois6b) te ha comentado, [los estilos y contenido de las ventanas emergentes `alert()` están predefinidos y no se pueden cambiar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/94842/css-para-alert-o-confirm-de-javascript/94863#94863).

Puedes usar en su lugar [los `Modals` de bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals).

Basta con llamar a [`.modal("show")`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals-options) para activar la opción `show` cuando cargue la página o bien configurar el atributo `data-show` y llamar a `.model()` sin parámetros de la siguiente manera:

```js
/* Desde javascript haciendo uso de "data-show" */
$(function() {
  $('#myModal').modal();
});
/* Desde javascript forzando su visualización */
/*$('#myModal').modal('show');*/
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Ejemplo</h2>
  <!-- Modal usando el atributo data-show="true" -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" data-show="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Mensaje de advertencia
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <img src="http://www.visitmt.com/binaries/medium/content/gallery/MTOT/responsive/hero-f/moose-calf_web.jpg" width="100%" />
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Los dialogos alert y confirm solo pueden mostrar textos. Utiliza un plugin de jquery como [jquery Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) o las [modales de bootstrap](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
         <img    style="width:150px" src="http://www.visitmt.com/binaries/medium/content/gallery/MTOT/responsive/hero-f/moose-calf_web.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
   <a class="btn btn-primary" href="index.php">Ir index</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Acá el problema sería que tocaría darle a un botón, la idea es que aparezca por si solo cuando ingrese al index.

Comment: Simplemente tendrias que agregarle otro boton que seria un link con la ruta de tu pagina index. Mira la respuesta actualizada con el ejemplo.

Answer (score 2):

Usando jqueryUI, Muestra botón para cerrar el popup y se abrirá solo al ingresar a la pagina:

HTML

```
<div id="alerta" title="Mensaje de Alerta" style="display:none"><img src="img/imagen.jpg"></div>
```

JS

```
$('#alerta').dialog();
```

Si no tienes jqueryui, agrega esto en el head:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

**opcional**,Puedes personalizarlo, ejem:

```
$( "#alerta" ).dialog({
  show: {
    effect: "blind",
    duration: 1000
  },
  hide: {
    effect: "explode",
    duration: 1000
  }
});
```

Esta es la pagina oficial para mas opciones: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar también `Dialog` de jQuery.

Este sería el estilo `Modal Message`. Es el código que presentan ellos en su página:

```js
  $( function() {
    $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        Ok: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
    });
  } );
```

```html
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Modal message</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="dialog-message" title="Download complete">
  <p>
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-check" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 50px 0;"></span>
    Your files have downloaded successfully into the My Downloads folder.
  </p>
  <p>
    Currently using <b>36% of your storage space</b>.
  </p>
</div>
 
<p>Sed vel diam id libero <a href="http://example.com">rutrum convallis</a>. Donec aliquet leo vel magna. Phasellus rhoncus faucibus ante. Etiam bibendum, enim faucibus aliquet rhoncus, arcu felis ultricies neque, sit amet auctor elit eros a lectus.</p>
</body>
```

Si observas [a la derecha de la página de jQuery Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-message), verás que hay otras posibilidades de implementación.